# Tired of creating /run/postgresql and setting read and execute writes after every reboot

Tags: linux, postgresql, archlinux

I'm running Arch Linux, I installed PostgreSQL as any other arch package. I'm running postgres with a local database located in my user directory. (`postgres -D /home/user/data/`) When I do so, I get the error `FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory`. Creating the directory /run/postgresql and giving the postgres user access solves this problem

```
$ sudo mkdir /run/postgresql
$ sudo chmod a+w /run/postgresql
```

however I'm tired of writing these commands every time I reboot, as /run gets cleared when rebooting. I could write a script to execute these commands, but I feel like I'm doing this the wrong way to begin with. Is there any way I could let postgres create its directory itself, or maybe have it not use /run/postgres for it's lock files in the first place?

Comment: Run your command as `postgres -k /tmp -D /home/user/data/`.

Comment: @alvits Works splendidly! If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres creates the lock file in `/run/postgresql` by default.

From the manpage:

> ```
>   -k directory
>           Specifies the directory of the Unix-domain socket on which postgres is
>           to listen for connections from client applications. The default  is
>           normally  /run/postgresql, but can be changed at build time.
> ```

Use `-k directory` to tell postgres to use a different directory.

Run your command as `postgres -k /tmp -D /home/user/data/`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** (By managing temporary directory /run/postgresql, /var/run/postgresql)

> Directory */run/postgresql* is a temporary directory. Path
> */var/run/postgresql* is usually a symbolic link to /run/postgresql.
>
> **systemd-tmpfiles** is mechanism to manage such temporary files and directories. **systemd-tmpfiles** creates temporary directories during
> boot and sets their owner, group and permissions.  It may read configuration files in three different locations. Files in
> /etc/tmpfiles.d override files with the same name in
> /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d and /run/tmpfiles.d.

We can create directory */run/postgresql* on the fly at boot time using **systemd-tmpfiles** mechanism by creating postgresql configuration file as below

```
echo "d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -" > /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```

**Solution 2** (By relocating PostgreSQL lock file location)

> Another way to fix the issue is to relocate the PostgreSQL lock file
> location. We can do so by using below query

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET unix_socket_directories='<any-existing-path-with-valid-permissions>, /tmp';
```

Here we can provide any path for PostgreSQL lock file which is already present on the system and have required permissions to manage lock files by postgres user.